# Git Grep Rev List Not Finding Test Commit

Tags: git, grep

I wish to search all remote Git files in all branches for either an AWS Access Key or AWS Secret Key. The code below works, but it doesn't pick up a recent test branch committed to the repo. Inside the test branch a secret and access key were added to a file. The file was then committed and finally pushed to remote.

Test branch workflow -

1. Currently in develop branch.
2. git checkout -b test-branch
3. vi test-file.json // added the access key and secret key
4. git add --all
5. git commit -m 'AWS Access and Secret Key Test'
6. git push -u origin test-branch

Now run the following on all code commits in the remote repo -

```
git rev-list --all | \
while read revision; do \
git grep --break --heading -n -P \ 
"(?<![A-Z0-9])[A-Z0-9]{20}(?![A-Z0-9])| \
(?<![A-Za-z0-9\/+=])[A-Za-z0-9\/+=]{40}(?![A-Za-z0-9\/+=])" \
$revision > /tmp/rev-list.log;  done
```

It finds entries but doesn't find the test-branch file. Any idea as to why this is happening / pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try the regex against the test file and see what happens.